# How do get visual topmost element - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, z-index

Is there a neat way to get the topmost element using jQuery?

I don't mean with respect to DOM hierarchy. i.e. `.closest()` is not what I need.

I mean, with respect to `z-index` and obviously it should be currently `:visible`

I was starting out to write a custom selector, but thought it would be better to see if there are better approaches.

Comment: in which [context](http://api.jquery.com/context/)?

Comment: @undefined: Ideally, the whole body.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
elem = [];
$("*").each(function(i){
    elem[$(this).index()] = $(this).css('z-index');
})

function compareNumbers(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

topmostIndex = elem.sort(compareNumbers).reverse();
alert(topmostIndex[0])
```

Comment: Up-voting this since it solves straightforward cases. But, the element with highest `z-index` may not necessarily be the top most right?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(':visible').each(function(){
    var z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);
    vat maxz = -1;
    if (!best || maxz < z) {
        best = this;
        maxz = z;
    }

});
```